# How to consume a SOAP WS from BPM with ArrayOfNameValuePair?

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, business-process-management

Everytime im getting a empty response for `port.op()`  I don´t know how to read the items of `ArrayOfNameValuePair`

my java function

```
 private static ArrayOfNameValuePair op() {
        pocodm.obtenerprovincia.ObtenerProvincia service = new pocodm.obtenerprovincia.ObtenerProvincia();
        pocodm.obtenerprovincia.ObtenerProvinciaPortType port = service.getObtenerProvinciaSoap();
        return port.op();
    }
```

envelop

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:obt="http://POCODM/ObtenerProvincia.tws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <obt:op/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <opResponse xmlns="http://POCODM/ObtenerProvincia.tws">
         <results>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">AZUAY</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">01</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">BOLIVAR</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">02</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">CARCHI</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">04</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">CAÑAR</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">03</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">CHIMBORAZO</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">06</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">COTOPAXI</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">05</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">EL ORO</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">07</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">ESMERALDAS</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">08</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">GALAPAGOS</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">20</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">GUAYAS</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">09</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">IMBABURA</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">10</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">LOJA</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">11</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">LOS RIOS</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">12</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">MANABI</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">13</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">MORONA SANTIAGO</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">14</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">NAPO</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">15</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">ORELLANA</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">22</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">PASTAZA</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">16</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">PICHINCHA</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">17</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">SANTA ELENA</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">24</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">SANTO DOMINGO DE LOS TSACHILAS</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">23</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">SUCUMBIOS</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">21</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">TUNGURAHUA</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">18</ns0:value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <ns0:name xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">ZAMORA CHINCHIPE</ns0:name>
               <ns0:value xmlns:ns0="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/">19</ns0:value>
            </item>
         </results>
      </opResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://POCODM/ObtenerCiudad.tws" xmlns:impl="http://POCODM/ObtenerCiudad.tws" xmlns:impl1="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:intf="http://POCODM/ObtenerCiudad.tws" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://POCODM/ObtenerCiudad.tws" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <import namespace="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/"/>
  <element name="op">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="text" type="xsd:string"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
  <element name="opResponse">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="results" type="impl1:ArrayOf_NameValuePair"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
    <schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:impl="http://POCODM/ObtenerCiudad.tws" xmlns:impl1="http://ectest556ws1:9081/schema/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <import namespace="http://POCODM/ObtenerCiudad.tws">
    <!--Add URI of the schema document for the imported namespace using 'schemaLocation' attribute.-->
  </import>
  <complexType name="NameValuePair">
    <sequence>
      <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="value" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="ArrayOf_NameValuePair">
    <sequence>
      <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" nillable="true" type="impl1:NameValuePair"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="ArrayOf_string">
    <sequence>
      <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="opResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="impl:opResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="opRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="impl:op">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ObtenerCiudadPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="op">
      <wsdl:input name="opRequest" message="impl:opRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="opResponse" message="impl:opResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ObtenerCiudadSoapSoapBinding" type="impl:ObtenerCiudadPortType">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="op">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="http://POCODM/ObtenerCiudad.tws/op"/>
      <wsdl:input name="opRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="opResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ObtenerCiudad">
    <wsdl:port name="ObtenerCiudadSoap" binding="impl:ObtenerCiudadSoapSoapBinding">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="http://ectest556ws1:9081/teamworks/webservices/POCODM/ObtenerCiudad.tws"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

what I get if I serialize

```
  JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer(); 
             out.println(   serializer.serialize( port.op() ));
ectest556ws1._9081.schema.ArrayOfNameValuePair@6d3f8e {"class":"ectest556ws1._9081.schema.ArrayOfNameValuePair"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was manage this response like a XHTMLReques, parsing the incoming XML to read the values.